# Powerpoint Animation with Grouping

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I want to do a powerpoint animation that has an animal walk past some seeds. I want to group the seeds with the animal once it gets to a certain point (I don't want to start out grouped), OR, I want the seeds to fall off of the animal once it gets to a certain place. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group objects and then apply different animation to it.  You will need to animate everything separately.

One idea is to have tour grouped object disappear at a certain point and have the second non grouped items appear.  This would provide the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As wbeard52 has pointed out, you cannot group / ungroup objects "on the fly". However you can apply the same annimation(s) to a number of objects at the same time. In your case

- select the animal and the seeds together
- add all the annimations you need to these selected objects
- once the animal and seeds have reached their destination, unselect them all
- then select the first seed and add its "falling off" annimation
- repeat the last step above for all seeds, one after another (or all of them together, if the "fall off" annimation is the same for them)